# Issue with IK-controlled Foot Floating in Editor during Ducking Movement with Rigify in Blender - Any Solutions?

Tags: gltf

I have an issue with GLTF file displaying on Web

Why is my IK-controlled foot floating in the editor despite looking fine in Blender during a ducking movement with Rigify

FYI
https://streamable.com/vzi3b0

It is working just fine on Blender
https://streamable.com/3wqtln

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I'll add that the glTF format does not store IK directly.  Animations with IK must be baked to sets of keyframes prior to export.

Comment: Thanks you guys, but it seems can not be resolved. I have tried baking the IK to FK, the result is the same/